# Como fazer uma ListView atualizar um titulo na parte superior, na medida que vou rolando o scroll do mesmo?

Tags: android, listview

Não sei como explicar muito bem o que eu quero sem imagens, mas eu preciso aprender a fazer uma ListView que mude de titulo na medida que você vai descendo... É basicamente como no HTML quando você faz páginas comprida e separa as seções por uma ancora, onde a ListView é dividida por seções e na medida que cada seção vai descendo, o título da seção é atualizado...

Comment: Algo [assim](http://javatechig.com/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android)? Ou um cabeçalho flutuante no topo da lista?

Comment: Isso mesmo @Paulo Rodrigues. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Não tenho certeza se é exatamente o que procura, mas existem algumas bibliotecas para manter o cabeçalho das seções da lista sempre visível. https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders
https://github.com/diegocarloslima/FloatingGroupExpandableListView

Comment: [Nesse link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45163/como-fazer-uma-listview-expans%C3%ADvel/45256#45256) mostrei como utilizar `ExpandableListView`, ele apresenta um resultado semelhante ao que você descreveu!

Answer (score 2):

1. Crie um **OnTouchListener** na sua **ListView** e procure pelo motionEvent **ACTION_MOVE**
2. Quando o método onTouch for chamado, pegue o id do primeiro elemento visível na listview com o método **getFirstVisiblePosition()**, e pegue o objeto com o  **getItemAtPosition()**
3. Para alterar o cabeçalho, se tiver usando uma **Toolbar** no XML, só alterá-la usando o **setTitle()**, se não tiver, você pode chamá-la com o **getSupportActionBar()**/**getActionBar()** e usar o **setTitle()**

```
listview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View button, MotionEvent motion) {
                if ( motion.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                        int firstVisibleID = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                        YourObj obj = listview.getItemAtPosition(firstVisibleID);
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(obj.getStringForTitle());
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```