# Como fazer uma ListView expansível?

Tags: android

Eu quero fazer uma `ListView` só que personalizada, ao clicar nela vai abrir uma aba em baixo para mostrar mais informações e o próximo item da `ListView` vai automaticamente descer um pouco para a aba abrir, segue o exemplo:

[image: A aba]

Na imagem percebemos que o usuário clica na parte branca e assim abre a parte preta mostrando mais informações sobre o item. Como fazer também para deixar em volta do item cinza e dentro do item branco?

Comment: já tentou usar o ExpandableListView? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: não, vou procurar saber melhor sobre ele, mesmo assim valeu!

Comment: Qualquer dúvida ou dificuldade edita sua resposta aqui que a gente te ajuda!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Conforme foi falado nos comentários, você pode utilizar [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html), vou dar um exemplo bem simples e você pode alterar/modificar conforme sua necessidade.

No exemplo vou simular uma mini lista de compras, onde os produtos serão exibidos em grupos, então vamos começar pelo *layout* principal (`/res/layout/layout.xml`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/elvCompra"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

*Layout* do item principal (grupo) (`/res/layout/grupo.xml`)

[image: Visual do item principal]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGrupo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:text="Grupo"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvQtde"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Qtde"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</LinearLayout>
```

*Layout* do subitem (item do grupo) (`/res/layout/item_grupo.xml`):

[image: Visual do subitem]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff9b999a"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvItem"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:text="Item"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvValor"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Valor"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Como estamos fazendo um `ExpandableListView` personalizado, podemos alterar as cores, as fontes e os tamanhos para que fiquem da maneira que queremos.

Para que as informações sejam exibidas no `ExpandableListView`, temos que criar um *adapter*, no caso um [BaseExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html), e implementar os métodos necessários conforme o abaixo:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Adaptador extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private List<String> lstGrupos;
    private HashMap<String, List<Produto>> lstItensGrupos;
    private Context context;

    public Adaptador(Context context, List<String> grupos, HashMap<String, List<Produto>> itensGrupos) {
        // inicializa as variáveis da classe
        this.context = context;
        lstGrupos = grupos;
        lstItensGrupos = itensGrupos;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        // retorna a quantidade de grupos
        return lstGrupos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        // retorna a quantidade de itens de um grupo
        return lstItensGrupos.get(getGroup(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        // retorna um grupo
        return lstGrupos.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // retorna um item do grupo
        return lstItensGrupos.get(getGroup(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        // retorna o id do grupo, porém como nesse exemplo
        // o grupo não possui um id específico, o retorno
        // será o próprio groupPosition
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // retorna o id do item do grupo, porém como nesse exemplo
        // o item do grupo não possui um id específico, o retorno
        // será o próprio childPosition
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // retorna se os ids são específicos (únicos para cada
        // grupo ou item) ou relativos
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // cria os itens principais (grupos)

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grupo, null);
        }

        TextView tvGrupo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvGrupo);
        TextView tvQtde = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvQtde);

        tvGrupo.setText((String) getGroup(groupPosition));
        tvQtde.setText(String.valueOf(getChildrenCount(groupPosition)));

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // cria os subitens (itens dos grupos)

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grupo, null);
        }

        TextView tvItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvItem);
        TextView tvValor = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvValor);

        Produto produto = (Produto) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        tvItem.setText(produto.getNome());
        tvValor.setText(String.valueOf(produto.getValor()));

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // retorna se o subitem (item do grupo) é selecionável
        return true;
    }
}
```

> **Nota:** deixei nos comentários o que é feito em cada método.

Como nosso exemplo trata-se de compras e produtos, criei a classe `Produto`:

```
public class Produto {

    private String nome;
    private Double valor;

    public Produto(String nome, Double valor) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Double getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(Double valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

}
```

Para finalizar, vamos na nossa `Activity`, criamos os dados e definimos o nosso adaptador:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);

        ExpandableListView elvCompra = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.elvCompra);

        // cria os grupos
        List<String> lstGrupos = new ArrayList<>();
        lstGrupos.add("Doces");
        lstGrupos.add("Legumes");
        lstGrupos.add("Outros");

        // cria os itens de cada grupo
        List<Produto> lstDoces = new ArrayList<>();
        lstDoces.add(new Produto("Pacote de bala", 4.5));
        lstDoces.add(new Produto("Pacote de chiclete", 3.5));
        lstDoces.add(new Produto("Bolo de chocolate", 50.0));

        List<Produto> lstLegumes = new ArrayList<>();
        lstLegumes.add(new Produto("Alface", 0.5));
        lstLegumes.add(new Produto("Tomate", 2.5));

        List<Produto> lstProdutos = new ArrayList<>();
        lstProdutos.add(new Produto("Chave de Fenda", 7.5));

        // cria o "relacionamento" dos grupos com seus itens
        HashMap<String, List<Produto>> lstItensGrupo = new HashMap<>();
        lstItensGrupo.put(lstGrupos.get(0), lstDoces);
        lstItensGrupo.put(lstGrupos.get(1), lstLegumes);
        lstItensGrupo.put(lstGrupos.get(2), lstProdutos);

        // cria um adaptador (BaseExpandableListAdapter) com os dados acima
        Adaptador adaptador = new Adaptador(this, lstGrupos, lstItensGrupo);
        // define o apadtador do ExpandableListView
        elvCompra.setAdapter(adaptador);
    }

}
```

O resultado final pode ser visto na imagem abaixo.

[image: Visual final do aplicativo]

**Referência**
[Android Expandable List View Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

**Extras**
[HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)
[LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)