# Itens de ExpandableListView clicáveis

Tags: android

Alguém sabe como eu faço para tornar os itens de uma ExpandableListView clicáveis?

Implementei esse modelo: [Como fazer uma ListView expansível?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45163/como-fazer-uma-listview-expans%c3%advel?noredirect=1&lq=1) e agora gostaria de poder clicar nos itens e abrir uma nova activity ou fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deve indicar à ExpandableListView um *OnChildClickListener* para ela usar/chamar sempre que um item é clicado:

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

        //abra aqui a nova Activiy

        return true;
    }
});
```

O parâmetro `groupPosition` recebe o índice do grupo cujo item(`childPosition`) foi clicado.
Em função desses dois valores abra a nova activity.